# Sass style throws undefined after compilation in NextJS

Tags: css, typescript, sass, next.js, tsx

I have peace of `sass` code:

```
.link
  display: inline-table
  text-align: center
  align-self: center
  margin: 5px 15px
  font-size: 20px
  color: black
  text-decoration: none
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out

.link:hover
  text-decoration: underline

.link-red:hover
  text-decoration: underline
  color: $color-red
```

And I have peace of `index.tsx` code:

```
<div>
   <a href={link} className={styles.link + " " + styles.linkRed}>{linktext}</a>
</div>
```

After compiling, at the exit I get this piece of compiled html:

```
<div>
   <a href="/auth/login" class="links_link__31hqZ undefined">Login</a>
</div>
```

As we can see style `link` have been succesfully compiled and attached but second file turned into `undefined`.

Why second style `link-red` turned into `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have `styles.linkRed` but in css you have `link-red` class with a dash. So in `jsx` you need to use `styles['link-red']`.

Next.js does not have configuration for automatic `camelCase` right now, but you can follow [this discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11267) for more details